# Retrofit - use query parameter with prefix

Tags: android, retrofit

I have small problem I'd like to solve. I need to create retrofit Service for following request

`https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:9788087270431`

And my API currently looks like:

```
public interface GoogleBooksApi {

    @GET("/books/v1/volumes")
    Call<BookResponse> getBooksByIsbn(@Query("q") String isbn);

}
```

But I have to use prefix "isbn:" every time. Can somebody tell me how to correctly do this?

Comment: instead of passing `9788087270431`, you could pass `"isbn:".concat("9788087270431")`

Comment: as I said "But I have to use prefix 'isbn:'" I'm just wondering whether is there any way without putting "isbn:" to each query

Comment: no that I know. query is a set pairs key/value separated by =

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here seems to be that you're misunderstanding the actual parameter that your call to getBooks is expecting.

```
@GET("/books/v1/volumes")
Call<BookResponse> getBooksByIsbn(@Query("q") String isbn);
```

Should actually be

```
@GET("/books/v1/volumes")
Call<BookResponse> getBooks(@Query("q") String query);
```

And then you can wrap the call to the API in a call like:

```
public void findByIsbn(String isbn) {
    GoogleBooksApi api = restAdapter.create(GoogleBooksApi.class);
    String query = buildIsbnQuery(isbn);
    api.getBooks(query);
}

public String buildIsbnQuery(String isbn) {
    return String.format("isbn:%s");
}
```

That way, if the requirement is no longer ISBN's, you don't have to change the actual functionality of your api code, you just need to add an additional query builder method, which makes it respect [open-closed principal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle).

Changing the retrofit code is not advisable and completely not necessary.

Comment: Yeah, I have named it because of my intention to query for ISBN only. Ok I'll let it be as it was and accepting as well. Thanks for open-closed principal, haven't heard about it before

Comment: You should read up on [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design))